# using a variable defined in one php file in another php file

Tags: php, html, global-variables

In my `adminpage.php` I have two hyperlinks which displayed as`option1 ,option2`. What I want is when Admin selects option1 it directs to a page named as `adminOption1.php`  and in this page I want to set in a variable, say named as 'adminType' (`$adminType=option1`) so that I can use the variable `adminType` in a different php file say, `adminDisplay.php`.  So that in `adminDisplay.php` based on whether adminType is set to option1 or option2 I can view different outputs.This admin's options are not stored in the database, it solely depends on the link which he clicks.

Can I set this as a session variable? I have my sessions as,

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM member WHERE `userName`='$n' AND password`='$p'");

if(mysql_num_rows($sql)==1) {
    $_SESSION['user']=mysql_fetch_array($sql);
```

and my member table has only `id`, `name` and `userName` as fields.
How can I do this.

Comment: print the result from `mysql_fetch_array($sql);` first, if it's a string for example you can set it to the sessions variable, also, please use MySqli and specifically PDO, mysql is insecure because of mysql injection for instance: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp

Comment: Make sure your form method is set to `POST`, when you post that field to your other page, you can get the result from $_POST variable.

Comment: @odedta Can I create a session variable as `$_SESSION['user']['option']`  ?Don't I need to have a field as `option` in `member` table in order to do this

Comment: Yes, you can create a session array. Sorry, i'm not following your question.

Comment: @odedta I don't have a form. Its simply a html <a href="adminOption1.php">Option1</a>

Comment: Then you need to use jQuery to hook an event to that `<a` tag and use `AJAX` to pass a variable to the next page.

Comment: If its not secure variable then pass it as url params like `...adminDisplay.php?variable=option1`. Then `$_GET[]` this value and verify if je is authorised or not.

Comment: @KirsSudh In `adminOption1.php` I have `include_once("adminDisplay.php")`.so should I do it as  include_once("adminDisplay.php?variable=option1"). Then in adminDisplay.php I use `if($_GET['variable']==option1)`

Comment: If you have included then why passing variables into adminOption? Else remove include and follow as you said above. Remember, varify once again in admindisplay whether user is same or not along with option1.